# HTML Appending an incrementing version number

Tags: html

I am having some issues coming up with a solution that will allow me to append an incrementing version number onto a existing name. Basically, I have a masterpage that contains a collection of documents. I have the ability to copy a document which then brings me to a detail page. From that detail page, I would like to have the name of the document I just clicked "copy" on along with an appended "version X" (where 'X' is the version number). If I save this new copy I'll be taken back to the main masterpage.

From there, if I wanted to make another copy, I would see the document name + "version X+1" and so on for each addtional copy.

As of right now I can only think of adding DateTime but I really want to get version numbers. Here's a snippet of what I have so far:

```
<input name="@Model.DetailObject.FormGroup.FormGroupName" type="text" value="@Model.DetailObject.FormGroup.FormGroupName-@DateTime.Now" />
```

Comment: This should be controlled by your back end, and html will print what you tell it to.  Or, you need to use JS to invoke a DOM function to clone/append an element/id.  You can't control this with html alone.

Answer (score 0):

Since the version is an attribute which describes the document itself, it would belong on the model and be persisted with the model.  So it should effectively be a property thereupon.

So if the model has a `VersionNumber` property (which increments every time it's saved to the data, which is back-end business logic) then you might have a property on the model for displaying the name with the version number.  Guessing on your model structure, something like this, perhaps:

```
public string NameWithVersion
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format("{0}-{1}", DetailObject.FormGroup.FormGroupName, VersionNumber);
    }
}
```

Then in the view you simply bind to that property:

```
value="@Model.NameWithVersion"
```

The point is that the logic belongs on the model, not in the HTML.

Comment: That makes sense but I guess I'm still confused on how the VersionNumber gets incremented in the backend.

Comment: @John: There are a number of ways to do it.  If saving the document object into a repository which returns the updated object, that repository could transparently increment the version number.  Or perhaps the business model itself could do it when constructing the object, so any "in flight" object which hasn't been saved yet is automatically considered "the next version".  There are a lot of considerations depending on the needs/features of the system, especially if concurrent saves are to be supported.